# How do I display an SVG image?

Tags: views, 9

I added the following code for a "Global: Custom Text" field.

```html
<div class="messages-list__item messages messages--warning" data-drupal-selector="messages" role="contentinfo" aria-label="Warning message" data-once="messages">
    <div class="messages__container" data-drupal-selector="messages-container">
        <div class="messages__header">
            <h2 class="visually-hidden">Warning message</h2>
            <div class="messages__icon">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M16,0C7.2,0,0,7.2,0,16c0,8.8,7.2,16,16,16c8.8,0,16-7.2,16-16C32,7.2,24.8,0,16,0z M18.7,26c0,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.6,0.7h-4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7v-4c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7h4c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.7V26z M18.6,18.8c0,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.5h-3.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.2-0.7-0.5L13,5.9c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.2h4.6c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.2C18.9,5.6,19,5.7,19,5.9L18.6,18.8z"></path></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="messages__content">
            <ul class="messages__list">
                {{ field_warning_affiliation }}
                {{ field_warning_investment }}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The SVG image is not displayed.

> [image: screenshot]

How do I display an SVG image?

Comment: My mistake.  As a workaround, you can probably save the SVG as a file and link to it as an image.

Comment: @Patrick Kenny yes it is possible but I find it cleaner with the code directly

Comment: Sure.  Another way to do this in code is to add a theme template for the view.  The downside of this approach is that it won't be editable in the Views admin UI.

Comment: Too bad Drupal does not support SVG in its interface. It complicates things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to add your SVG, or if you want it inline you can also add it inside a twig template (like this: `views-view-field--yourviewid--nothing.html.twig`). Then add something like this wherever you want it in the file:

```
{{ include('@youtheme/images/picto.svg') }}
```

Within your `yourtheme.info.yml`, add this:

```
components:
  namespaces:
    yourtheme:
      - .
```

Enable the [components](https://www.drupal.org/project/components) module.

or

```
{{ include(directory ~ '/images/picto.svg') }}
```

or

```
{{ source(directory ~ '/images/picto.svg') }}
```